# Making chrome extensions on chromium vs. chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Pretty simple question-- is it possible to create google chrome extensions via Chromium, and have that same extension be used with people running Chrome on different OS's?

I'm developing on Ubuntu.

Comment: Why not do it in Google chrome for Ubuntu then?

Comment: I was having trouble installing it but it seems like that's what I need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible; however, Chromium included in Ubuntu will probably seriously lag behind main Chrome versions.

You won't benefit from new APIs available to Chrome users, as well as be unable to test the extension for the majority of users.

Your best bet is, indeed, to install Chrome from Google's repositories.